# is it possible to use datetime in an array?

Tags: php

Is it possible to use `DateTime` to grab every date from now till one week ago and than make an array, for example

```
1-4-2014
1-3-2014
1-2-2014
```

And so on

Currently this is my code

```
<?php
$datetime = new DateTime(); 
$datetime->format('Y-m-d');

$arr = array(/* diverse dates */);
foreach ($to_remove as $item) 
{
    $is_smaller = ($to_remove->format('U') <= $datetime->format('U'));
    if ($is_smaller) 
    {
        $arr = array_filter($arr, function($item) use ($to_remove) {
            return !preg_match("/$to_remove by /", $item);
         });             
    }
}
```

Basically I need it to check the current date and the dates from one week ago and then remove the string from the array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the file `ban_list.txt`, but you should consider to use a database for this.

Comment: I tried to actually remove the file-interaction part from your question as it seems rather not part of the problem you ask about. However I must admit, it still does not turn it into a proper programming question, therefore I just vote to close. Please consult the Help centre about how to ask and improve questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `DateTime::add`.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("now");
$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$days = 7;
$resultArray = array();
for($i=0 ; $i<$days ; $i++){
    $dateTime->add($dateInterval);
    $resultArray[] = $dateTime->format('d-m-Y'); 
}
```

Result:

```
array(7) { 
    [0]=> string(10) "05-01-2014" 
    [1]=> string(10) "06-01-2014" 
    [2]=> string(10) "07-01-2014" 
    [3]=> string(10) "08-01-2014" 
    [4]=> string(10) "09-01-2014" 
    [5]=> string(10) "10-01-2014" 
    [6]=> string(10) "11-01-2014" 
}
```

Edit:

My fault, i overread the description "one week ago".
Also you can use [DateTime::sub](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php)

Comment: It seems i cant get this to work with my scripts for some reason

Comment: So how would i change it to 1 week ago i tried the sub but couldnt get it to work

Comment: You have to replace the `add` with `sub` in the for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `DateTime` class and `DateInterval` with `DatePeriod`:

```
$now = new DateTime( "now");
$yourInterval= new DateInterval( 'P1D'); //here you set interval per one day 
$yourPeriodOfSevenDays= new DatePeriod( $now, $yourInterval, 7); // here you will set to what piriod of time get inerval


foreach($yourPeriodOfSevenDays as $day) {
    $date = $day->format( 'd-m-Y'); 
    $resultArray[] =  $date ;
}
```

Now you will have all dates in array

```
array(8) { [0]=> string(10) "04-01-2014" [1]=> string(10) "05-01-2014" [2]=> string(10) "06-01-2014" [3]=> string(10) "07-01-2014" [4]=> string(10) "08-01-2014" [5]=> string(10) "09-01-2014" [6]=> string(10) "10-01-2014" [7]=> string(10) "11-01-2014" }
```

Comment: The OP wanted "from now till one week __ago__", you've gone the other way :)

Comment: Yes i need a week ago :p

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way I can think of:-

```
$lastWeek = new \DateTime('-7 days');
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new \DatePeriod($lastWeek, $interval, new \DateTime());
var_dump(iterator_to_array($period));
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/aZSTB).

Even simpler, if you like one liners:-

```
$period = new \DatePeriod(new \DateTime('-7 days'), new \DateInterval('P1D'), new \DateTime());
var_dump(iterator_to_array($period));
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/lkXBs).

Then again, you can use a DatePeriod object in a foreach loop, so you may not need an array:-

```
$period = new \DatePeriod(new \DateTime('-7 days'), new \DateInterval('P1D'), new \DateTime());
foreach($period as $day){
    echo $day->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/YiPnY)

Reference http://php.net/datetime